# what does "insertions and deletions" mean and how the numbers are calculated

Tags: git, git-diff, diffstat

when use `diffStat` or `git diff`  to analyze the code,it often shows the result below,

`71 files changed, 10938 insertions(+), 947 deletions(-), 3103 modifications(!), 3027 unchanged lines(=)`

but I do not know what the `insertions and deletions` mean？

- does it mean the increased or deleted line count？
- How those insertions/deletion numbers are calculated ？

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. It is about how those numbers are calculated, which I attempt to explore in my answer below.

Comment: yes,i also want to konw how those are calculated,maybe I need to modify my title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that message printed in [`diff.c#print_stat_summary()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a28705da929ad746abcb34270947f738549d3246/diff.c#L1503-L1535)

Those numbers are computed in [`diff.c#show_stats()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a28705da929ad746abcb34270947f738549d3246/diff.c#L1761-L1775), where the numbers of lines added or deleted are tallied.

The actual computation for a given place is in [`diff.c#builtin_diffstat`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a28705da929ad746abcb34270947f738549d3246/diff.c#L2510-L2526) (which calls [`diff.c#diff_populate_filespec()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a28705da929ad746abcb34270947f738549d3246/diff.c#L2736-L2742) if one of the files is a binary).

Answer (score 3):

If you add a new line, it's 1 insertion. If you delete a line, it's 1 deletion. If you modify one line, it's 1 deletion and 1 insertion.

Comment: I am finding that is not always the case. When I append a new entry to a JSON file, Git does not report any deletions even though there is a line with "}" that changed to "},". Exactly when does Git take shortcuts like this one?